# Embedding kotlin-compiler in java application

Tags: java, kotlin, jar, jvm

I have downloaded non-native kotlin compiler which is in jar format from here https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.4.30.

In that there is file called `kotlin-compiler` which I want embed in my java application to compile kotlin source file. How can I do that?

I know that I have to import that jar file in java source. But after that I have no idea what function call triggers compiler.
Guys any idea how can it be done?

Comment: There is a CLI for compiler in `kotlinc\bin` folder. Here is a manual for it: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html
You may look into `kotlinc.bat` and try to reverse-engineer it (spoiler: it calls `org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main`), but I don't think it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over [this thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/use-kotlin-compiler-from-java-without-files/7251/8) which mentions that Kotlin 1.1 includes an implementation of JSR-233, which refers to the generic [Scripting API included in Java 9 and above](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/scripting/java-scripting-api.htm#JSJSG109).

I didn't find ready-made Java code, but you should be able to piece it together: some details are in [this post](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/embedding-kotlin-as-scripting-language-in-java-apps/2211/9). Then, have a look at this [this Kotlin class](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/src/test/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/script/jsr223/KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineIT.kt): it's a test class that demonstrates various ways to interact with the Kotlin compiler.

Your Java code would need to call the same APIs that are called by the Kotlin class. If you have trouble reading the Kotlin code, you can [turn the Kotlin code into Java source](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file).